# Github workflow: get the from branch of a pull request

Tags: github

I have github workflow which gets triggered on a issue comment in a PR. Inside the workflow I would like to get the name of the branch where de PR is coming from.

Like in this image the "from" branch.
[image]

Is there github provided variable which will contain the "from" branch where the PR is coming from?

I tried a few variables provided by github, e.g. GITHUB_REF_NAME, GITHUB_HEAD_REF. But either there are empty or I got "main" as result.